# Check box selection and list item click on the same listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I have implemented a custom listview with checkboxes in the single choice mode of the android listview.I want a functionality such that when I click on the checkbox the row corresponding to that check box must get added(or rather say the "Person" object shown in that row should get added to another list and be removed from that list) and on itemclick on that listview should take me to another screen in android.I tried the other ways but they specify that the checkbox needs to be focasable:false.Also I want the click listener to work on the check box only.Please any suggestions or help on these.Thanks in advance

This id the xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/projects_check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/project_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/projects_check"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/projects_check"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/projects_check"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/projects_check"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my onitem click listener code..

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long arg3) {
        Projects info = (Projects) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        info.toggleChecked();
        ProjectsHolder viewHolder = (ProjectsHolder) view.getTag();
        viewHolder.getmChoiceSelect().setChecked(info.isChecked());
        if (viewHolder.getmChoiceSelect().isChecked()) {
            completed_projects.add(info);
            mCompProjAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            projects_list.remove(info);
            mProjAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: suggestion use custom Adapter and handle click event of checkbox and textview there instead of `setOnItemClickListener` for list view

Comment: But how can I get the click of the checkbox into the fragment since because the checkbox is implemented in the custom adapter

Comment: you have to write click event of check box and textbox in your custom Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

To manage click onto the row itself, you can just write listener for listView itself.
 This is how i manage checkbox click.

```
 class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BeanClass> {

            private ArrayList<BeanClass> items;

            public FieldPlannedAdapter(Context context,
                    ArrayList<BeanClass> items) {
                super(context, R.layout.custom_list_row, items);

                this.items = items;
            }

            public class ViewHolder {

                protected CheckBox checkbox;
                protected TextView name;

            }

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {

                final ViewHolder viewHolder;

                if (convertView == null) {

                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_row,
                            null);
                    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                    viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.checkIsMissed);

                    viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.txtViewMTPname);


                    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


                    viewHolder.checkbox
                            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                                    final BeanClass item = (BeanClass) cb
                                            .getTag();

                                    item.setSelected(cb.isChecked());


                                    if (cb.isChecked()) {
                                        // DO SOMETHING

                                    } else {

                                    }



                                }
                            });


                } else {
                    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                BeanClass item = items.get(position);
                viewHolder.name.setTag(item);

                viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(item);


                viewHolder.name.setText(item.getName());

                viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(item.isSelected());

                if (viewHolder.checkbox.isChecked()) {
                    // DO SOMETHING

                } else {
                    // DO SOMETHING
                }

                return convertView;
            }
        }
```

**Custom row example :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/card_ui"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewMTPname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Customer Name"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewMtpDarCity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="dgdgdgdg"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkIsMissed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Missed" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I tried doing this but after doing your procedure,the check box still remains a part of the list row and so I am not able to implement the onitem click listener

Comment: onItemClick listener needs to be implemented on listview, in onCreate

Comment: Yes i have done that in my fragment class that contains the listview but since the list row is custom the check box comes in the foreground and i am not able to click anything apart from the checkbox.Could you please add the onitem click code as well.Just a brief explanation would be good for ex: show a toast on item click.Thanks in advance

Comment: I asked you that because i implemented that onitem click listener but still couldn't still get the click

Comment: I'll add an example of row. Try to adjust your layout according to that,

Comment: The Thing is, you actually need to add an attribute "descendFocusability" in layout, that should take care of row click

Comment: Your layout is missing some things. Check mine and update accordingly